# Where is the rendered viewport shading mode in Blender 2.78

Tags: rendering, interface, 3d-view

I'm trying to find the *Rendered* viewport shading mode.

I saw in a tutorial that it was accessed with the <kbd>Z</kbd> key. In the tutorial it displayed many options, but for me it doesn't.

Any ideas?

This is what I am looking for:
[image: What I Need]

Answer (score 2):

Here it is in my 2.78: note this is using official PIE menu addon.

[image]